# portion of areas of two triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

let us consider following picture

[image]

we are given that this two line is parallel and  also $AC=1/3 * AD$,we should find  portion of areas of  $ABC$ and  $BCD$,now because  $AB$ is  one third of  $AD$, it means that $AC=x$ and $AD=3*x$,from which $CD=2*x$,now as i know  , ratios of areas of  two triangle is equal to  square of  ratios of  two sides of this triangles,or  in other word,if

$AC/CD=1/2$

ratios of their areas should be  $1/4$,but answer is simply $1/2$,because $ABC$ is oblique,we may say that these two triangle has same  height,but does it change something?suppose that we have two any triangle with  ratios of  sides be let say $1:3$,what should be  ratios of their areas? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have confused that with ratio of areas for similar figures.

For this case, since the area of triangle is $\frac{1}{2}$base $\times$ height, another triangle with twice the base would have twice the area, given the same height.

Your last question is different, since now the 2nd triangle has triple side lengths for all three sides, the two triangles are similar, and the ratio of areas is $1^2:3^2$.

Comment: but if  two length are in some proportion we  could not consider as similar?

Comment: For triangles, two sides in proportion is not sufficient. What about the remaining side?

Comment: that is what i wanted,so we can't determine also portions of height  right if one one pair of sides portion is given

Comment: For the case in your figure, if you consider the bases of the triangles to be _AC_ and _CD_, then both heights of the triangles are the distance between the parallel lines.

Comment: but in general case  we can't right